# Compare all elements within an array with another array

Tags: c++, c

So i am having difficulty understand a rather simple algorithm. If i want to compare all the elements within one array to another how would it work? For instance

```
For ( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
     For ( k = 0; k < size; k++)
     { 
          Do something if arrays are the same or not
     }
}
```

Both i and k loops would just carry the same slot in the array. If i add a - 1 or + 1 it would just check the last or next slot... But what if i wanted to check 1 to 3 or the whole array preferably.

Comment: For a array `A` indexed by `i`, you are comparing all the elements in array `B` starting from `k=0` to `k<size`; then incrementing `i` to compare the next element and so on...

Comment: If you use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) ithen it has [comparison "built-in"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp).

Comment: Question is: are the elements in the arrays in the same order? If yes, then you only need one loop. If no, then you need an additional array to keep track of which items in the `k` array have been used. Either that, or sort the arrays so they *are* in the same order.

Comment: Instead of "Do something etc," try printing i and k, you will directly understand how these loops work.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you consider "the same".  If you want them to be in the same order, it can be a little simpler.

```
for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
    if (arrayOne[i] != arrayTwo[i])
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the order doesn't matter, it can get a little more complicated.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int valueFound = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){

        if (arrayOne[i] == arrayTwo[k]){
            valueFound = 1;
        }
    }
    if (valueFound == 0)
        return false;

}
return true;
```

But this assumes that the arrays are the same size.  And it really only checks to see that all the values from `arrayOne` are inside `arrayTwo` so it is not exactly what you're looking for.  I do hope that this provides some direction to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect algorithm.

You can write your own function, it will be like this.
Note that `a[]` in function arguments will be replaced by compiler with `*a`

```
template<typename T>
bool arraycmp(T *a, size_t a_size, T *b, size_t b_size)
{
    if(a_size != b_size) // If sizes is not same, we know that arrays not equal
        return false;


    for(size_t i = 0; i<a_size; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i]!=b[i]) // Just do check, and if array element mismatch return false
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

or like this, with one `size_t`

```
template<typename T>
bool arraycmp(T *a, T *b, size_t size)
{   
    for(size_t i = 0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i]!=b[i]) // Just do check, and if array element mismatch return false
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or just use library function `memcmp`